# MS Access: Enter information on Header that applies to all records entered below

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create an MS access form to capture data from a paper purchase order.

The paper form has a header with boiler plate information (Date ordered/PO Number/etc...) that applies to all information on the purchase order. The detail lines then contain the information which is unique (I.E. Part #, Serial #, etc...). Each detail line is a unique record.

To make it easy on the user, I want them to only have to enter the "header" information once per PO, and then enter all the detail lines. When data entry is complete, I can have a button to clear out the header info and enter new info.

I only have a single table behind this form (since I'd like all the header information to apply to each detail line/record). Splitting this into two tables (I.E. tbl_detail_lines and tbl_POs) seems un-necessarily complex. The problem is that not having 2 tables seems to make having a form/sub-form impossible. Is there an easy way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Two tables conforms to relational database concept. Build form/subform arrangement. Don't 'clear' the form, move to NewRecord row. Otherwise, you need a bunch of code to 'carry forward' the 'header' info to each new record. Which is simpler is a matter of perception.

Comment: What June7 wrote. Purchase Orders and Order Items are different entities, and therefore belong into separate tables.